# How do you output the current value of LimitRequestBody on Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, apache2.4, amazon-linux

I'm having issues uploading a file (via WordPress) on one of the sites my customer uses. I'm on Apache 2.4.39 (Amazon) & PHP 7.0.33.

I've set the `LimitRequestBody` directive in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file to a very large number (like `104857600 = 100 MB`) and also set it to zero (0).

The file I'm testing with is 11 MB in size. Is there a way, likely using command line, that I can output the `LimitRequestBody` variable via for a given virtual host or the server as a whole? I'm trying to verify what the actual value is and I can't find any documentation on how to do that, outside of using "grep" to pull the value from the conf file... which is the value I set, which seems to be ignored.

I've searched the `/etc/httpd/` directory for any `LimitRequestBody` entries (using grep) and only found the single reference (I created) in the `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file.

I've confirmed PHP `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` are both 32M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my specific case, the three variables that affect the size of an allowed uploadable file are:

```
LimitRequestBody -> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
post_max_size and upload_max_filesize in the /etc/php.ini
```

My problem was that the WordPress installation had a plugin (All In One WP Security & Firewall), that was adding a LimitRequestBody 10240000 to the .htaccess file.  Once I finally found that entry and used the "Custom Rules" section to overwrite that to value I wanted, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know whats the current running configuration for your PHP, you can simply create a phpinfo file:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

After that if there is a discrepancy you need to make changes in the php.ini file, which is the system wide configuration file:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file